# Connection string to read csv in utf-8 folder

Tags: c#, csv, connection-string

I'm new in C# and i got a problem with upload data from CSV to database, please help me

I want to allow operators selecting CSV file in flexible directory by using class OpenFileDialog like this:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
...
filename = dlg.FileName;// get full path of selected file
string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename); //get directory
string excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" + fileDirectory + "\\\";Extended Properties=\"text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;CHARSET=65001;\""; //connection
using(OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr);)
{
   string csvFiename = Path.GetFileName(filename);
   string excelQR = "select * from ["+ csvFiename + "]";
   ...
}
```

Above code work OK if i select CSV file in none UTF-8 folder ex: C:\Users\nmhoan\Desktop\New folder
. But if i select file in UTF-8 folder ex: Desktop\Vẽ layout, i got a message:

> *System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: ''C:\Users\nmhoan\Desktop\Vẽ layout\' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled
>   correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file
>   resides.'*

I spent so much time to find a solution but still can't fixed.
Please help me to fix this problem.

thank you with highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a CSV file you shouldn't use Excel for this purpose, cause it has to much hassle (like it must be installed on the machine where your program runs, false interpretation of numbers as dates, hard to use correctly, changing values is a mess, etc.). Instead use a specialized library that is able to read and write CSV files. There are plenty of them for C# but I personally prefer [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).